# Security and Policies in OAS export from azure apim

Tags: azure, openapi, azure-api-management

Let’s say I have different backend services exposing their api in azure api management (apim). The different services rely on different security methodologies, e.g. jwt tokens and subscription key. The backend developers specify these differences and upload them to apim using the OpenApi Spec (OAS). Then I find out that [Security definitions are ignored](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-api-import-restrictions) so where would the developer have to specify this information? In descriptions instead? Or what is the proper way of conveying security information in apim.

In addition, the apim can have policies set regarding security. These policies are not exposed in OAS either. With the exception of the subscription key, however this is just default behaviour even if one disables the subscription required tag in the api settings in apim, the subscription key is still present in OAS.

So how do one go about informing users about the backend services security and the apims security when it is not present in OAS? Is there some configuration that I am missing?

The idea for my apim is to have different suppliers of backend services so they could have different security levels - It can be specified in OAS - but will not give me anything in the exported version from apim.

In addition, I as an owner of apim will set some security settings - which will still not be present in OAS. So what should the consumer do to understand how to use the backend endpoints exposed in the downloaded OAS’s?

Comment: You can refer to [Importing an OpenAPI API into Azure API Management Service](https://soltisweb.com/blog/detail/2020-08-19-importingopenapiapiintoazureapim) and [openapi-backend](https://github.com/anttiviljami/openapi-backend)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT Those links are how to create an OAS and add them to apim. I like the backend link for testing but cannot see how it links to my question? All of this I know - and should be stated in the text clearly if not please let me know so I can edit the ambiguity. The question is how do I ensure that security information is present in the exported OAS from apim and since this is an issue in apim. What is the proper way to convey this information?

Answer (score 1):

There's a few parts to this question...

At the company where I work; we use APIM, but we don't define our Open API spec (OAS) in there. IMO APIM is not really intended to be used as an API documentation tool.

We define & document the OASs in [Swagger Hub](https://swagger.io/). Swagger Hub are the company behind the Swagger spec, which has since been rebranded to Open API spec. Swagger Hub is a commercial offering, but I *think* there's also a free tier.

As you're probably aware, you can define multiple security schemes in your Open API spec e.g.

```
securitySchemes:
    jwt_token:
        type: oauth2
        flows:
            authorizationCode:
                authorizationUrl: {my-authorization-url}
                tokenUrl: {my-token-url}
    apim_subscription_key:
        type: apiKey
        in: header
        name: X-API-KEY
```

You can then apply these security schemes to your Open API spec (either at the root level or on individual operations).

```
paths:
    '/{version}/users':
        get:
            summary: 'Search for users'
            description: 'blah'
            security:
                - jwt_token: []
                - apim_subscription_key: []
```

In Swagger Hub you can 'view documentation' to render the Open API spec in a 'Swagger UI'. You can configure `servers` to point to different locations (e.g. APIM) when you invoke operations in the Swagger UI e.g.

```
servers:
    - description: 'localhost'
      url: http://localhost:{port}
      variables:
        port:
            default: "8089"
    - description: 'APIM DEV'
      url: {apim-url}
```

*see [here](https://swagger.io/specification/#server-object) for more information about configuring servers.*

In the Swagger UI rendered by your OAS, you click the authorize button and authenticate to one of your specified security schemes as follows:

[image]
[image]

and change the server that you're pointing to via the drop down:

[image]

Switch to APIM server and invoke your API operations to call your APIs fronted by APIM.

You can publish the API in Swagger Hub and make the API publicly accessible to your consumers.

In APIM, you'll probably need to implement policies such as [validate JWT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#ValidateJWT), but as you've mentioned these don't live in the OAS. Ideally your APIM config would all be in source control, which would includes both the OAS as well as things like APIM policies and other config. It's not actually trivial to do all of this - there's a PluralSight course that I watched recently that was a pretty good overview about how to set up SCM for APIM - see [here](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/azure-api-devops-management/description).

There's an integration in Swagger Hub to publish OASs directly to APIM, which might also be interesting, but I haven't used this as part any workflows. See [here](https://support.smartbear.com/swaggerhub/docs/integrations/azure-api-management.html).

WRT to your API consumers, you can either

- Give them your OAS from Swagger Hub, which includes security schemes, servers, etc.
- Just give them access to the Swagger UI documentation, which is a nice UI for your OAS with the ability to authenticate to your specified security schemes and make API request to your API running in different locations e.g. localhost, or your DEV/SIT/UAT APIs running in Azure behind APIM...

Comment: Thank you - really Nice answer! I think it still has the same problems. I mean if there are defined security elements in the OAS in swagger hub - this information is not shown in apim - right ? So if a consumer comes into the developer portal in azure he still needs additional information to consume the api from some where right? Or did I misunderstand your answer? I will watch the pluralsight video this weekend 

Comment: Correct - certain elements seem to get automatically removed in APIM, which makes it unsuitable (IMO) as the go to place for documentation - FWIW the 'servers' element is another one that gets removed. Instead of getting API consumers to go to the APIM developer portal for API documentation, I'd get them to go to Swagger Hub (specifically the generated Swagger UI page for your OAS) to get information about your API. They can consume the APIs against your APIM instance, but API documentation comes from Swagger Hub.

Comment: FYI., there's also some API mocking capabilities in Swagger Hub, which could be useful for getting something out there and available to consumers very quickly, but I haven't really played with this too much... probably comes in useful if/when the API consumers are starting a project at the same time as the API developers and the APIs aren't actually available yet...

Answer (score -1):

One way to solve this problem is store your keys and secrets on Azure Key Vault and access them from your front end application.

Another way is by using Dapr along with the APIM. Dapr helps in building event-driven, resilient distributed applications. To consume application secrets, Dapr has a dedicated secrets building block API that allows developers to get secrets from a secret store.

Check this [Secrets Management](https://docs.dapr.io/developing-applications/building-blocks/secrets/secrets-overview/) document for more information.

Dapr integration in the Azure API Management (APIM) service was released last year only. This new capability enables operations teams to directly expose Dapr microservices as APIs and make those APIs discoverable and easily consumable by developers.

You can check this Microsoft Documentation for more information.
[Dapr integration in Azure API Management Service](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/opensource/2020/09/22/announcing-dapr-integration-azure-api-management-service-apim/).

Comment: I do not think this really relates to my question. So specifically what I am looking for is in the OAS you can add security information - e.g. jwt tokens should exist in headers. This information is then used to generate clients for web, micro services or apps. The security information from OAS disappears in azure apim. Which is then a problem for the consumer of the generated clients since it is now missing information - the consumer now has to guess or contact the developer so not a smooth flow.